# Losing data because of different Android signatures

Tags: android

I've been using my application for a while and produced a lot of data in it. Now it came time to upgrade it but the problem is that I've bought a new laptop and I can't upgrade the application due to different signature another IDE is using. It is impossible now to save the data, right?

**Update:** I didn't use any .keystore intentionally, I was just installing from Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter along as you use the same .keystore when you sign the application.

Comment: I didn't use any .keystore intentionally, I was just installing from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the keystore and the same options.

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that you have uploaded your application without any `signing` certificate, basically copying the `.apk` from the `/bin` folder? As far as I know this is not possible.

If you indeed upload it with your `.debug` certificate, then I am afraid you will not be able to update your app, since as you have noticed, every installation of `Android ADT` creates a different `.debug` certificate on each machine.

Comment: No, I was doing just nothing, merely installed it from Eclipse. You are saying that Eclipse is using a certificate which I can take and use on another machine? But I can't because I am on new laptop

Comment: what do you mean by "installed it from Eclipse" you are talking about an app that you personally used? not something published on market?

Comment: yes, indeed, I'm talking about the app I personally created and using now.

Comment: okay. sorry then, missunderstood your question. I don't think you can recover the data if it is in internal storage of the app. If you did store it on sdcard... yes, but I don't think you did.